Dependency of a JavaFX module to another Java Gradle module fails in IntelliJ
I am running IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.1.4 and want to create a simple project with multiple inter-dependent modules using Gradle and Java 21.
The root directory contains a settings.gradle:
rootProject.name = 'demo'
include 'the-library'
include 'core'
include 'ui'

and in the root I have 3 modules: "the-library", "core" and "ui".
First, I want to use code from the-library in the core module, so in the core's build gradle it says
dependencies {
    implementation project(':the-library')
    ...
}

Works like a charm, I can use the-library's code in the core module.
Now to the issue: I also created a ui module using JavaFX (went through IntellJ's "New Module" wizard and created a JavaFX module).
In its build.gradle I added the dependency to the core:
dependencies {
  implementation('com.github.almasb:fxgl:17.3') {
    exclude(group: 'org.openjfx')
    exclude(group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin')
  }

  implementation project(':core')
  testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}")
  testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}")
}

But a Gradle sync reveals an error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\dev\demo\ui\build.gradle' line: 43

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'ui'.
> Project with path ':core' could not be found in root project 'ui'.

The problem seems to be related to the nature of the JavaFX-based module, because otherwise 'core' would not be able to have a successful dependency to 'the-library' as mentioned before.
Anyone can help me please?

I tried to remove the JavaFX 'ui' module and re-create it
I tried to re-create the whole project
I tried to use a different version of IntelliJ (2023.something)


How to use JavaFX in a library using Maven.  That also uses SceneBuilder, but you can ignore those sections if they don't apply.  I try to avoid gradle, so have no advice on how to accomplish something similar using gradle.  Nor do I use kotlin or fxgl, so there might be some complications by adding those additional systems.

Could you provide the full settings.gradle file and the full three build.gradle files? Also, please provide the project's directory structure (your OS should have some kind of tree command you can use for this)? One thing I find odd is the error message says, "Project with path ':core' could not be found in root project 'ui'", but your root project is demo, not ui.

UI Project expects CORE Project to be in it's directory. You can specify the path to it as include("core")
findProject(":core")?.projectDir = File("..\..\path\to\project\core")
Other options are: to adjust your Projects' structure or install CORE to Maven Local and refer to it as a regular dependency from UI.

Having no second settings.gradle was definitely an issue, thanks for pointing that out, Simon!
I finally have resolved my issue by using a workaround:
Instead of creating a JavaFX module from the wizard, create a simple Java module and import all JavaFX later (just import the javafxplugin in the ui module's Gradle)
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.1.0'
}

Add the desired module dependencies in the ui's gradle just as described above
dependencies {
    implementation project(':core')
    testImplementation platform('org.junit:junit-bom:5.10.0')
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
...
}

Wrap the UI's entry point in another class, otherwise IntelliJ will complain with

"JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this
application":

This works:
public class HelloWorld
{
    public static class TheUI extends Application
    {
        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
            primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
            Button btn = new Button();
            ...
            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
            primaryStage.show();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(TheUI.class); // main entry point
    }
}

Et voilà, you can write a UI application accessing other modules' functionality.

I tried creating a new module using IntelliJ in the way you describe and it adds it as an entirely new Gradle root project, rather than a subproject. Hence why you can't access the other subprojects.
At a minimum, you need to remove the settings.gradle file that the IDE added in the ui folder, and unattach the new Gradle project that IntelliJ added in the Gradle sidebar. Then IntelliJ will not try and build that module as a separate root project.
